# Форматирование строки с input в дробь с двумя знаками после разделителя, динамически

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Здраствуй, есть вопрос, как можно форматировать строку из  input (я использую Form.Control от React)  в вид дроби (без букв, символов, кроме точки, ну и если возможно с запятой)
Например:

- Ввод      Вывод(Правильно)
- 1         1
- 12        12
- 123       123
- 1234      1234
- 1234.5    1234.5
- 1234.56   1234.56
- 1234.5678 1234.56
- 123.4567  123.45

(Извените за форматирование)

Было замечательно если могли бы подсказать как можно сделать форматирование как у валют

например: 1,234,567.89   12,345.6   1,234   123

Не коректные данные 1.1. 0.. ..1 .1. 1111.111.1

И да, код который получает даные значение:

```js
<Form.Group controlId='formGridAmount' as={Col}>
        <Form.Label>Amount</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
            autoComplete='off'
            name='Amount'
            type='text'
            value={ Amount }
            onChange={e => {
              setAmount(e.currentTarget.value)
            }}
            required={!isSearch}
            disabled={!props.limit.active}
           />
      </Form.Group>
```

Я как понимаю можно использовать регулярное выражение но как сделать чтобы ето было динамически т. е. сразу когда пишет пользовать отображалось даное число (напр. пользователь пишет число без . 12345678 и устанавливаеться значение 12,345,678(если с запятой ) а если 123456.78  -> 123,456.78)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может комуто нужен будет тысячный разделитель для input type=text
В Form.Control

```html
   onChange={e => {
              setAmount(formatAmountFromLimit(e.currentTarget.value))
            }}
```

```js
export const formatAmountFromLimit = (limitAmount) => {


    if (isNaN(limitAmount)) {
        let allow = /[a-z]|[^\d\.\,]/gi.exec(limitAmount)
        let dot = /\./g.exec(limitAmount)
        if (allow != null)
            limitAmount = limitAmount.slice(0, allow.index) + limitAmount.slice(allow.index+1)
        if (dot != null)
            limitAmount = limitAmount.slice(0, dot.index) + limitAmount.slice(dot.index+1)
    }

    if( limitAmount[limitAmount.length-1]==='.' ) {
        if (limitAmount[limitAmount.length - 2] === '.')
            limitAmount = limitAmount.slice(0, -1)
        return Number(limitAmount).toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")+'.'
    }

    if (/(\.\d{3,})?$/.exec(limitAmount)[0].length > 0)
        limitAmount = limitAmount.slice(0, -1)

    return Number(limitAmount).toLocaleString('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
}
```